# Debug Area loads empty with missing NSLog?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, admob, nslog

```
 NSLog(@"iAd banner shown");
```

Above is an example of my NSLog message i'm using. However, the debug area appears but no NSLog message appears in it. I'm also having an issue with AdMob test banner. I am using AdMobSDKiOS7.0.0

```
    GADRequest *request =[GADRequest request];

    request.testDevices = @[ @"testDeviceIDNumber" ];  

    [adMobView loadRequest:request];
```

I'm supposed to get a message from Google stating my test device ID number to get test ads on my device. When I run the device the debug area appears completely empty. No NSLog statements and no test device ID Number.

Did I accidentally click something off in Xcode? What can I do to get messages in Debug area again?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use YOUR code after getting your ID.

First just connect your test device and put code like this:

```
adMobView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,self.view.frame.size.height - 50, self.view.frame.size.width, CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait).height)];//banner on the bottom
self.adMobView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx";
self.adMobView.rootViewController = self;
self.adMobView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.adMobView]; 
[self.adMobView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

..and run your app. You will see a message like this in your Debug area:

```
<Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ @"testDeviceNumber" ]
```

Comment: @Jet I forgot about your NSlog problem. I thing it is placed where not run (if condition or something)?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you hid your console.

[image]